# AtlBeacons' BeaconManager.startMonitoring(Region) replaces the current monitored region

Tags: android, kotlin, altbeacon

`BeaconManager.monitoredRegions` shows just one region is being monitored, when `BeaconManager.startMonitoring()` has been called twice:

```
beaconManager.startMonitoring(regionA)
Log.d(TAG, "Started observing beacon: ${entity.a}")
beaconManager.startMonitoring(regionB)
Log.d(TAG, "Started observing beacon: ${entity.b}")
 
Log.i(TAG, "Monitoring regions: ${beaconManager.monitoredRegions}")
```

The above code produces the following logs:

```
2021-11-17 14:25:10.804 3918-3918 D/BeaconRepository: Started observing beacon: 58857b49-3560-4152-ad6d-779ec1137f66
2021-11-17 14:25:10.833 3918-3918 D/BeaconRepository: Started observing beacon: 9e3464fd-33e8-45b7-85c2-73d8e159dcd3
2021-11-17 14:25:10.833 3918-3918 I/BeaconRepository: Monitoring regions: [id1: 9e3464fd-33e8-45b7-85c2-73d8e159dcd3 id2: null id3: null]
```

If `beaconManager.startMonitoring(regionA)` and `beaconManager.startMonitoring(regionB)` are swapped, the following logs are given:

```
2021-11-17 14:29:40.211 4291-4291 D/BeaconRepository: Started observing beacon: 9e3464fd-33e8-45b7-85c2-73d8e159dcd3
2021-11-17 14:29:40.232 4291-4291 D/BeaconRepository: Started observing beacon: 58857b49-3560-4152-ad6d-779ec1137f66
2021-11-17 14:29:40.232 4291-4291 I/BeaconRepository: Monitoring regions: [id1: 58857b49-3560-4152-ad6d-779ec1137f66 id2: null id3: null]
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening, or what I am miss-understanding? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the definition of your `Region` objects, but I suspect they might look something like this:

```
val regionA = Region("my region", "9e3464fd-33e8-45b7-85c2-73d8e159dcd3", null, null)
val regionB = Region("my region", "58857b49-3560-4152-ad6d-779ec1137f66", null, null)
```

In the sample above, the first parameter to the constructor is a unique id for identifying the region when calling the API. **This unique id must be different for every region you define**, and if it is not, calls to start monitoring for regionA followed by regionB will tell the library to **replace** regionA with regionB.

If you want to monitor both regions at the same time, just make sure the first parameter is unique like this:

```
val regionA = Region("my region A", "9e3464fd-33e8-45b7-85c2-73d8e159dcd3", null, null)
val regionB = Region("my region B", "58857b49-3560-4152-ad6d-779ec1137f66", null, null)
```